# Spring-integration JMS publish subscribe in both inbound and outbound

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to use the example project of Spring-Integration JMS for JMS integration, Which I have done succesfully. How ever I have a slightly different set of requirement. Where I need to listen from 1 JMS Broker using Publish Subscribe pattern and, I need to send the same listened JMS message to another Kafak Queue/or nay other queue. I am struggling with the configuration,  as of now I have configured only for request and response queue. Here are the configuration. Please  help.

**Common.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
        <property name="cacheProducers" value="false"/>
    </bean>

     <!-- <bean id="requestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="queue.demo"/>
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="replyQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="queue.reply"/>
    </bean>
 <bean id="requestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="queue.request"/>
    </bean>

    <integration:poller id="poller" default="true" fixed-delay="100"/>

</beans>
```

**InboudChanelAdapter**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd">

    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
            destination="requestQueue"
            channel="jmsInChannel" />

    <channel id="jmsInChannel" />



    <beans:beans profile="testCase">

        <bridge input-channel="jmsInChannel" output-channel="queueChannel"/>

        <channel id="queueChannel">
            <queue />
        </channel>

     </beans:beans> 

</beans:beans>
```

**OutboundChannelAdapter.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
        xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd">

        <stream:stdin-channel-adapter id="stdin" channel="stdinToJmsoutChannel"/>

        <channel id="stdinToJmsoutChannel"/>
        <channel id="jmsInChannel" />

        <jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsout" channel="jmsInChannel" destination="requestQueue"/>

    </beans:beans>
 **DemoConfig.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd">

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
        <property name="cacheProducers" value="false"/>
    </bean>


     <bean id="connectionFactory2nd" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
        <property name="cacheProducers" value="false"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="replyQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" >
        <constructor-arg value="queue.reply"/>
    </bean>
 <bean id="requestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="queue.request"/>
    </bean>

  <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
        destination="requestQueue"
        channel="jmsInChannel" 
       connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

   <jms:publish-subscribe-channel id= "jmsInChannel"/>
   <jms:topic id="Topic"></jms:topic>
   </<jms:channel>     

   <jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsout" channel="jmsInChannel" destination="replyQueue" connection-factory="connectionFactory2nd"/>

    <integration:poller id="poller" default="true" fixed-delay="100"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have enough theoretical knowledge, so you should go to the Docs and Books about Spring Integration. You don't feel well what is `MessageChannel` yet.

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
        destination="requestQueue"
        channel="jmsInChannel" />
```

Means: listen on the `requestQueue` destination and send the Spring Integration Message to the `jmsInChannel`.

If you are going just to send that message to the another JMS destination you should do something like this:

```
<jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsout" channel="jmsInChannel" destination="replyQueue"/>
```

And be sure that there is no more subscriber to that `jmsInChannel`, because it is a `DirectChannel`.

According to your current config you have additional subscriber as `<bridge>`. In this case the `Round-Robin` balancer works on that `jmsInChannel` and the first message will be sent to the first subscriber, and only the second - to the second, and so on.

If you want accept that message by both subscribers you should change `jmsInChannel` to the `<publish-subscribe-channel>`.

More info you can find from docs.

Comment: Thanks Artem. But How can I differentiate between two ActiveMQ broker. Here I have configured for 1. How to differentiate that

Comment: You should just configure a new `CachingConnectionFactory` bean for that Broker. All JMS adapters have a `connection-factory` attributeto inject s specific `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`

Comment: Hi Artem, Here I do not want both the channel to be subscribers rather I want the flow like, receiving JMS message from One Message broker topic by spring integration , here an inbound adapter will be defined, then the same spring integration message will be put in a channel where the outbound adapter will pick and put in a separate Message broker topic. Bottom line is I want all the JMS messaged to be passed through SPring integration. I have updated the config in the question according to your recommendation in democonfig.xm.

Comment: You don't remove the second `jmsout` definition from your config. That one without `connection-factory`. Yes, according to your request, there is no reason in the `publish-subscribe-channel`. And have it like `<jms:publish-subscribe-channel>` is an error at all. From other side keep in mind that having the same `id` on different components cause an unexpected issue, when the last one wins. So, your runtime doesn't have `jmsout` with `connection-factory`. Please, be careful.

Comment: OK. I see you removed the second `jmsout`. So, you just should come back to the `<channel id="jmsInChannel" />`. Please, read more what `<jms:publish-subscribe-channel>` means: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jms.html#jms-channel

Comment: Gone through the doc today. But not able to understand how the components will interact all together. Here  in the above configuration If I am defining a  <jms:topic id="Topic"></jms:topic>, then how the publisher that is inbound adapter broker will publish to it and , the same topic can be utilized by other borker ie outbound broker will be able to get .

Comment: The `<jms:publish-subscribe-channel>` isn't related to this question. Please, take a look to the docs first of all and maybe you won't have issue to raise a new question here.